# logstash to s3 how to prefix a unique number as folder

Tags: amazon-s3, plugins, output, logstash

I am trying to send logs to `S3` and simulate a folder structure like 
`dev/logstash/1234/logfilename.txt`
some how my this configuration is not working. How do i pass the num value? this is my output conf to `s3`

```
   output{
     s3{
      region => "us-east-1"
      bucket => "xx-yy-zz"
      prefix => "dev/logstash/appname/%{num}/"
      time_file => 1
     }
   }
```

the %{num} doesnt evaluate. how to pass that value?

Comment: You have to create that value earlier, where does that %{num} be supposed to come from?

Comment: i did but looks like its not supported in prefix, means the num value wont be pulled from variable for version 2.4

Comment: Don't use 2.4 then, it is a very old version.